# How can I avoid end of paragraphs being seen as end of part of array?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a completed PHP script, which processes an uploaded text file and imports the data into a MySQL table.

Each time the text file is uploaded:

1. the existing table is dropped
2. a new table is created with the same name
3. and all the new data is inserted into the new table.

The text file is created by a company's in-house database software which is the reason for this process.

The fields/values in the text file are delimited by a backslash, which the script successfully explodes:

```
$this_array = explode("\\", $this_string);
```

It then ends that part of the array by looking for the line break at the end of each row (the end of that part of the array would be the end of the database row). eg. in the example text file (below) the line break comes after `'Row1Data for colname4'`. That part of the array should then become a row in the database table.

**However the problem is that the script is spitting out this error:**

```
Error #1136:Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

This is caused by the multiple paragraphs in the text file also having line breaks at the end of them (see example text file below).

PROBLEM: I don't know how to avoid the end of the paragraphs being interpreted as the end of the row/part of the array. **How can I continue to use this process with multiple paragraphs of text, without them being interpreted as the end of that part of the array?**

Example text file contents:

```
colname1name\colname2name\colname3name\colname4name
Data for colname1\Row1Data for colname2\This is a Row1 Paragraph to go in colname3
This is another Row1 Paragraph to go in colname3
This is yet another Row1 Paragraph to go in colname3\Row1Data for colname4
Row2Data for colname1\Row2Data for colname2\This is a Row2 Paragraph 1 to go in colname3
This is another Row2 Paragraph to go in colname3
This is yet another Row2 Paragraph to go in colname3\Row2Data for colname4
```

There's a lot of code in the script, but I think this is the most relevant part:

```
//
//---------------------------------------create table--------------------------------
//
$text_string="CREATE TABLE `area` (";
//loop thru names
for ($n=0; $n< count($name_array); $n++){
$name_array[$n]=trim($name_array[$n]);//trim needed here
if($name_array[$n]=='population'){//population field has to be INT

    $text_string.= "`".$name_array[$n]."` INT(8) NOT NULL,";    

}elseif($name_array[$n]=='towndescription'){//description field has to be TEXT

    $text_string.= "`".$name_array[$n]."` TEXT NOT NULL,";  

}else{
$text_string.= "`".$name_array[$n]."` varchar(250) NOT NULL default '',";
}
}
//remove last comma
$string_len=strlen($text_string);
$string_len=$string_len-1;
$text_string=substr($text_string,0,$string_len);
//
$text_string.= ") ENGINE=MyISAM ";
$db_sql_query = $text_string;
$db_result = @mysql_query($db_sql_query, $db_connection) or die ("Error #" . mysql_errno() . ":" . mysql_error());
print $text_string."<BR><BR>";//////////    
//
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//now loop thru $array
//

for ($n=1; $n<count($array) ; $n++){

    $text_string= "INSERT INTO `area` VALUES (";
    //for each line explode
    $this_string=$array[$n];
    $this_array = explode("\\", $this_string);
    for ($i=0; $i< count($this_array); $i++){
        //replace ' with html code - &#8217;
        $this_item=$this_array[$i];
        $this_item=trim($this_item);//trim needed here
        $this_item = str_replace("&", "and","$this_item" );
        $this_item = str_replace("'", "&#8217;","$this_item" );
        $this_item = str_replace("\"", "","$this_item" );//escaped "    

        //$this_item = str_replace(" ", "%20","$this_item" );
        $text_string.= " '".$this_item."' ,";
    }
    //remove last comma
    $string_len=strlen($text_string);
    $string_len=$string_len-1;
    $text_string=substr($text_string,0,$string_len);
    //
    $text_string.= ") ";
    $db_sql_query = $text_string;

    $db_result = @mysql_query($db_sql_query, $db_connection) or die ("Error #" . mysql_errno() . ":" . mysql_error());
print $text_string;//////////   
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the "NTH ROW: " marker present in the file? If so, you could split the lines on those instead of line breaks.

Comment: Use prepared/parameterized queries and your problem goes away automatically.

Comment: _but when it puts each row into an array_ - I had trouble understanding from there. The exploding on backslash is understood, but what do you do with each part (with each part presumably including line break characters)? Can you tweak that part of your question (by editing it) so that it is clearer?

Comment: No the 'Nth row' was just for illustrative purposes, they just contain standard text. Unfortunately Brad, my knowledge of PHP is good enough to tweak, but I don't have a good enough idea of where to start with required queries to help in this case. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks Halfer, I've just edited it, is it any clearer now?

Comment: See my answer below. (Bear in mind that you need to use @halfer to get people's attention here - although it is in the help text below the comment box, it is easily missed! You will get notified of this comment automatically however, as it is your question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone who helped here. After more research I started to realise that necause I was importing a text file it would make sense to look at converting the text to CSV before it was uploaded to the database (meaning getting rid of all those slashes).

Once I had made sure that the text in the text file was in the correct CSV format, I used a script by [Jay Williams](https://gist.github.com/jaywilliams/385876) to convert a comma separated file into an associated array. The first row should contain the array keys.

This all meant that because the multiple paragraphs of text were enclosed with a single pair of quotation marks that all paragraphs were recognised correctly by my script (with a little bit of adjustment), without them being interpreted as the end of that part of the array.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you can just explode on backslash, and then grab each column as you need it, with the assumption that all columns will be supplied for a row. So, you grab columns 1, 2, 3 and 4 - and then upon getting the forth, write the row, and then restart.

Here's some code:

```
<?php

$text = "
Data for colname1\\Row1Data for colname2\\This is a Row1 Paragraph to go in colname3
This is another Row1 Paragraph to go in colname3
This is yet another Row1 Paragraph to go in colname3\\Row1Data for colname4\\
Row2Data for colname1\\Row2Data for colname2\\This is a Row2 Paragraph 1 to go in colname3
This is another Row2 Paragraph to go in colname3
This is yet another Row2 Paragraph to go in colname3\\Row2Data for colname4
";

$lines = explode('\\', $text);
$totalCols = 4;

$currentCol = 0;
$currentRow = 0;
foreach ($lines as $line)
{
    echo $currentCol . '/' . $currentRow . ': ' . $line . "\n";
    $currentCol++;
    if ($currentCol == $totalCols)
    {
        $currentCol = 0;
        $currentRow++;
    }
}

?>
```

This will output thusly:

```
0/0: Data for colname1
1/0: Row1Data for colname2
2/0: This is a Row1 Paragraph to go in colname3 This is another Row1 Paragraph to go in colname3 This is yet another Row1 Paragraph to go in colname3
3/0: Row1Data for colname4
0/1: Row2Data for colname1
1/1: Row2Data for colname2
2/1: This is a Row2 Paragraph 1 to go in colname3 This is another Row2 Paragraph to go in colname3 This is yet another Row2 Paragraph to go in colname3
3/1: Row2Data for colname4
```

[Here's a live demo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/gs2-c1f) you can play with.

I had to tweak your data to get it working - "Row1Data for colname4" doesn't have a backslash terminator.

Comment: Hi @halfer, thank you very much for your help here and your suggestion. I couldn't quite get your solution to work correctly for my requirements, which was probably due to my explanations not being spot on. Sorry that the information behind the question was a bit hard to understand, and thanks again.